# AngularJS Expression breaks with StencilJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, stenciljs

I have a custom select web component created with StencilJS and I am using it in AngularJS like this:

```
<my-select>
  <my-option ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.value}}
  </my-option>
</my-select>
```

The problem is that whenever I push a new item on the `items` array (`items.push({key: 'some', value: 'Some Value'})`), the expression seems to print also it's own syntax in the DOM like this:

[image]

This is the `<my-option>` StencilJS component structure:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div class="option-container" onClick={this.selectOption(this)}>
      <slot />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related issues: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1070 https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1083 https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/1948

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried some newer Browser like the newest Firefox or Chrome? I faced some really stupid issues because Edge Browser for example does render the `<slot` tag as an String initially and just renders the innerHTML once. The other Browser will keep the slot as an DOM Element so its more dynamic.